# php not activated after upgrade to 18.04 TLS

Tags: 18.04, php

To my great stupefaction, php did not work on the 18.04 version. It did work for phpmyadmin. In looking at the configuration files php7.2.conf and phpmyadmin.conf I noticed that in the latter a directive:
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
existed which was not in the former. Further investigation lead to the discovery that in /etc/mime.types the line(s) for the php extension were marked as comment! Activating at least the line for .php made php working!!

Hubert

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. When I tried it, the browser downloaded my `phpinfo` page instead of displaying it. I had to run `sudo a2enmod php7.2 && sudo systemctl restart apache2` per [install-php-7-2-18-04](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/#install-php-7-2-18-04) and [how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04?comment=70395). (The first site also had `a2enmod php7.2`, but it was under the section, 'How to change the PHP version you’re using'.)